# problem with Get a specific row from the array

Tags: php, laravel

I receive information from the api, the output of which is as follows

```
Array
(
    [DOGE/USDT] => Array
        (
            [symbol] => DOGE/USDT
            [timestamp] => 
            [datetime] => 
            [info] => Array
                (
                    [takerFeeRate] => 0.001
                    [makerFeeRate] => 0.001
                    [takerCoefficient] => 1
                    [makerCoefficient] => 1
                )

        )

    [ETC/USDT] => Array
        (
        [symbol] => ETC/USDT
        [timestamp] => 
        [datetime] => 
        [info] => Array
            (
                [takerFeeRate] => 0.001
                [makerFeeRate] => 0.001
                [takerCoefficient] => 1
                [makerCoefficient] => 1
            )

        )
)
and...
```

Now I wrote the following code to get a specific row of the array

```
    $coins =  $coinex->fetch_tickers();
    $searchCoin = ['DOGE/USDT'];
    $filteredArray = array_filter($coins, function($row) use ($searchCoin){
        return $row['symbol'] === $searchCoin;
    });
    print('<pre>');
    print_r($filteredArray);
    print('<pre>');
```

But it gives me back an empty array. Where is the problem? How should I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
$searchCoin = ['DOGE/USDT'];
```

by

```
$searchCoin = 'DOGE/USDT';
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case you need only

```
$coins['DOGE/USDT']
```

but the mistake you made is here:

```
$searchCoin = ['DOGE/USDT'];
```

You are searching for an array. You need:

```
$searchCoin = 'DOGE/USDT';
```

Answer (score 2):

$searchCoin = ['DOGE/USDT'];

in this line, you are declaring a new array which is wrong in your case

change above to this:

$searchCoin = 'DOGE/USDT';

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.